# HTML5 support with Rails 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I just started learning Rails 4.0.2. I was wondering if there is anything(any gem?) which allows the support of html5 in rails .html.erb pages..

So basically, lets say, If I create an email field in my .html.erb, It would look like as :

```
<%= f.text_field :email %>
```

And in html5, you can simply use

```
<input type="email" ..>
```

which make sure that email format is correct..

My question is:

Is it possible to use <%= f.email ... %> in .html.erb pages using the help of anything?

I hope I made my question clear. I won't mind writing more about it if it is not clear..

Comment: I would say Rails doesn't care about what you write in your HTML, but I'm not 100% sure this is right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails does support HTML5, try this in your view

```
= f.email_field :email
```

Just make sure your layout starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag (which is added for you by default).

You should read more about this and other view-related helpers [in the excellent Guide on the topic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), these HTML5 helpers are detailed in the [Other Helpers section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#other-helpers-of-interest)

Comment: Aaahaha. Nice. This is what I was looking for.. Cheers!